# Auto-complete both - and - - arguments

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have the following Python script in file `test.py`:

```
import argparse

library_list=["LibraryA","LibraryB","LibraryC"]

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-l", "--library", required=True, choices=library_list,
   help="Choose library")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

library=args["library"]
print(library+" chosen")
```

I want to be able to auto-complete the arguments for `-l/--library`. For this I have this Bash auto-complete script:

```
lib_list="LibraryA LibraryB LibraryC"

function libs()
{
case $3 in
    -l) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$lib_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
esac
}

complete -F libs test.py
```

This script however only completes the `-l` flag as I have not been able to get it to work for `--library`. I have tried adding another line for the `case` statement with `--library` instead of `-l` or using `-l | --library) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$lib_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;`, but both don't work.
How would I get this to work?

Comment: Both adding a line with `--library)` and the same action and modifying the line to have `-l|--library)` instead of of `-l)` work here. Did you perhaps forget to `source` the bash file after you did the changes?

Comment: Yes you are right, when I tried it again it did work, stupid me...